# MVC4 Task<IEnumerable> not awaitable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking at examples, just trying to understand the `await` keyword in a MVC AsyncController. I feel like the following should work as I am just trying to return a list asynchronously. This was just an example for understanding the `async` keyword:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var s = await SelectAsync();
        return View(s);
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<Student>> SelectAsync()
    {
        var ctx = new Test.MVC4.Repository.StudentDataContext;
        return await ctx.Students.ToList(); 
    }
```

I get that `Task<IEnumerable<Student>>` is not awaitable. I was under the impression that `Task`s are awaitable.

Updated: What about something like this (assuming the EF code has been abstracted to the .Select method?

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var s = await SelectAsync();
        return View(s);
    }

     private async Task<IEnumerable<Student>> SelectAsync()
     {
        return _repo.Select();
     }
```

Or do I also need to use Task.Run inside the SelectAsync method as well? I'm used to doing this sort of thing in client-side so I appreciate the help here with these methods...

Answer (score 7):

You are calling `await`on `ctx.Students.ToList()`. This method (`ToList()`) does not return a `Task` and therefor is not awaitable.